# replacing XML values in For-Each and returning in function

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing, xmldom

The script I have here is attempting to do recurse through an XML file, storing each RegEx match (stored in a search array) into 2 result arrays; 1 for start date, 1 for end date.
Ubounds of both arrays are checked for equality then the text is passed to a function that uses XMLDOM to find the End_Date node in each parent node, then passes that text to another function, adding 30 days and then passing it back, replacing the previous value.  Then it's supposed to write back the contents to the file and save it.

I've got a few problems here.  1.  I can't get the +30 day value to be passed back to anything past the first parent node--memory space seems to retain the +30 day value from previous For-Each iteration.  2.  I can't write anything back to the file.

I was initially writing for text files, but the format changed to XML as the requirements changed on our project.

I'd love to be able to do this all in XMLDOM in vbscript and just use functions to do specific data changes.  But my main concern is my sloppy script not doing the basics.

Can anyone help me by pointing out the flaws in the loops I'm running?  I've hit a wall and just can't seem to make any more progress!

Here's the XML file I'm reading(shortened to 2 Ad nodes w/ a ton of child nodes removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLFeederRoot>
<ADS_CREATE_TIME>2016-06-07T01:35:39</ADS_CREATE_TIME>
<Ad>
  <Ad_Number>d00524224</Ad_Number>
  <Start_Date>2016-08-20T00:00:00</Start_Date>
  <End_Date>2016-08-20T00:00:00</End_Date>
  <Status>Run</Status>
</Ad><Ad>
  <Ad_Number>d00524225</Ad_Number>
  <Start_Date>2016-08-20T00:00:00</Start_Date>
  <End_Date>2016-08-20T00:00:00</End_Date>
  <Status>Run</Status>
</Ad>
</XMLFeederRoot>
```

Here's the script:

```
'Setting the Regular Expression object and setting occurrences to all in strings searched.
Set objRegEx= CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Global= True

set Shell= createobject("wscript.shell")
Dim FSO, FLD, FIL, TS, strDate, strEDat, i, d, c
Dim strFolder, strContent, strPath
Const ForReading= 1, ForWriting= 2 

strFolder= "C:\Scripts\Run"

Set FSO= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get a reference to the folder you want to search
set FLD= FSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

'loop through the folder and get the files
For Each Fil In FLD.Files

'Open the file to read
Set TS= FSO.OpenTextFile(fil.Path, ForReading)

'Read the contents into a variable
strContent= TS.ReadAll

'Close the file
TS.Close


reDim arrMR(1,1)
    arrMR(0,0)= "(\s+)(<Start_Date>(.*?)<\/Start_Date>)"
    arrMR(1,0)= "(\s+)(<End_Date>(.*?)<\/End_Date>)"


For i= 0 to Ubound(arrMR)
    objRegEx.Pattern= arrMR(i,0)
    Set objMatches= objRegEx.Execute(strContent)


d=0

    For Each objMatch in objMatches
        If i= 0 Then
            If d>0 Then
                reDim Preserve arrStart(d)
            Else
                reDim arrStart(d)
            End If
                arrStart(d)= objMatches.Item(d).SubMatches(2)

                'Wscript.Echo arrStart(d)
        ElseIf i<> 0 Then
            If d>0 Then
                reDim Preserve arrEnd(d)
                ReDim Preserve arrMatch1(d)
            Else
                reDim arrEnd(d)
                ReDim arrMatch1(d)
            End If
                arrEnd(d)= objMatches.Item(d).SubMatches(2)         
                arrMatch1(d)= objMatches.Item(d).SubMatches(1)

        End If



        If objRegEx.Pattern<> arrMR(0,0) Then
            If (ubound(arrStart)= ubound(arrEnd)) Then
                'Wscript.Echo "Ubounds Match"   
                            Parse strContent
                            strContent= Parse(strContent)
            Else
                'Wscript.Echo "Start & End Dates do not match"
            End If
        End If          
            d= d+ 1 'increment to next match

    Next

Next    

'Close the file
TS.Close

'Open the file to overwrite the contents
Set TS= FSO.OpenTextFile(fil.Path, ForWriting)

'Write the contents back
TS.Write strContent

'Close the current file
TS.Close

Next

'Clean up
Set TS= Nothing
Set FLD= Nothing
Set FSO= Nothing


Function Parse(ParseContent)

  'Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   =   FSO.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\Users\j.levine\Desktop\XML Feeder                 Scripts\Test_Files\monvid.txt")
  Dim oXML   : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")  
  Dim strXMLSDat, strXMLarrStartD, XMLEDat
  oXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  oXML.async = False
  oXML.loadXML(ParseContent)

  If 0 = oXML.parseError Then
     Dim sXPath3 : sXPath3    = "//XMLFeederRoot/Ad[End_Date=Start_Date]"
     Dim ndlFnd : Set ndlFnd = oXML.selectNodes(sXPath3)
     If 0 = ndlFnd.length Then
        WScript.Echo sXPath, "not found"
     ElseIf 0<> ndlFnd.length Then       
        'WScript.Echo "found", ndlFnd.length, "nodes for", sXPath
        Dim ndCur, oldNode
        For Each ndCur In ndlFnd    
            oldNode = oXML.selectsinglenode("//End_Date").text
            oldNode= XMLSplitArray(oldNode) 'Pass current Date into Array and add 30 days & return as node text
            Set newNode= oXML.selectSingleNode("//End_Date")
            newNode.text= oldNode
            WScript.Echo ndCur.xml

        Next
        'WScript.Echo "We have nothing to replace"
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo oXML.parseError.reason
  End If

  Parse= ParseContent
End Function


Function XMLSplitArray(strval1)

dim XmlSA, XmlSA2, XMLEDat

XmlSA = split(strval1, "-")
XmlSA(2) = Left(XmlSA(2), 2)
strXMLDate = XmlSA(1) & "/" & XmlSA(2) & "/" & XmlSA(0)
strXMLDate30 = DateAdd("d", 30, strXMLDate)

XmlSA2 = split(strXMLDate30, "/")

'Add zero to the left
XmlSA2(0)= Right("0" & XmlSA2(0), 2)
XmlSA2(1)= Right("0" & XmlSA2(1), 2)

XmlSA2(1) = XmlSA2(1) & "T00:00:00"
XMLEDat = XmlSA2(2) & "-" & XmlSA2(0) & "-" & XmlSA2(1)
XMLSplitArray= XMLEDat

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Text and XML files don't use file locks by default just overwrite the original file using xmlDoc.Save monvidPath.

```
Sub setAdEndDate(monvidPath)
    Const sXPath  = "/XMLFeederRoot/Ad/End_Date"

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

    xmlDoc.Async = "False"
    xmlDoc.Load(monvidPath)

    Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes(sXPath)

    For Each n In colNodes

        n.Text = SplitArray(n.Text)

    Next

    xmlDoc.Save monvidPath

End Sub

Function SplitArray(strval1)
    Dim SplitArray1, SplitArray2, strSDat

    splitArray1 = Split(strval1, "-")
    splitArray1(2) = Left(splitArray1(2), 2)
    strDate1 = SplitArray1(1) & "/" & SplitArray1(2) & "/" & SplitArray1(0)
    strDate30 = DateAdd("d", 30, strDate1)

    SplitArray2 = Split(strDate30, "/")

    'Add zero to the left
    If Len(SplitArray2(0))<2 Then 
        SplitArray2(0)= Right("0" & SplitArray2(0), 2)
    End If
    If Len(SplitArray2(1))<2 Then 
        SplitArray2(1)= Right("0" & SplitArray2(1), 2)
    End If

    SplitArray2(1) = splitArray2(1) & "T00:00:00"
    strSDat = SplitArray2(2) & "-" & SplitArray2(0) & "-" & SplitArray2(1)
    SplitArray= strSDat

End Function
```

Comment: In the simplest case, yes, this would be easier and I've done that in other parts of this script which I removed as they weren't the trouble spots. I think I've made this overly complex because of the many changes that are being thrown at me, and I'm trying to stick a lot of different ways of doing things together.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas was right w/ the KISS method. I took a big step back, and started over.

Here's what I've come up with.  It does what I need regarding the Date+30 and writing back to a file.  I think this method is cleaner and will allow me to run my other text massaging through functions.

My questions about this new script are: 
1.  can this be done without having to write to a new file?  Keeping to 1 file is easier.
2.  Can I avoid cloning the node and deleting the original one and directly change the original node's value?
3.  I seem to be missing how to get that last node `<Status>` onto it's own line.

Script:

```
Dim xmlDoc: Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.load "C:\Scripts\Run\MonVid-SHORT.xml"

Dim xmldoc2: set xmldoc2 = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
Dim strSkeleton : strSkeleton= "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
                                "<XMLFeederRoot>" & _
                                "</XMLFeederRoot>"
xmldoc2.loadXML(strSkeleton)
xmldoc2.save  "C:\Scripts\Copy\New_MonVid-Short.xml"
xmlDoc2.async = False
xmlDoc2.load "C:\Scripts\Copy\New_MonVid-Short.xml"
Dim sXPath : sXPath     = "/XMLFeederRoot/Ad[Start_Date=End_Date]"


For Each n In XMLDoc.SelectNodes(sXpath)
    set l = n.cloneNode(True)
    q= l.selectSingleNode("/End_Date").text

    strSDat=SplitArray(q)

    l.removeChild(l.childNodes.item(2))
    set Stat= l.selectSingleNode("/Status")
    set Parent= Stat.parentNode
    set EDate= xmlDoc2.createElement("End_Date")
    EDate.appendChild xmlDoc2.createTextNode(strSDat)
    Parent.insertBefore EDate, Stat

    xmldoc2.documentElement.appendChild parent

Next

xmlDoc2.save xmldoc2.url


Function SplitArray(strval1)
dim SplitArray1, SplitArray2, strSDat

splitArray1 = split(strval1, "-")
splitArray1(2) = left(splitArray1(2), 2)
strDate1 = SplitArray1(1) & "/" & SplitArray1(2) & "/" & SplitArray1(0)
strDate30 = DateAdd("d", 30, strDate1)

SplitArray2 = split(strDate30, "/")

'Add zero to the left
If Len(SplitArray2(0))<2 Then 
    SplitArray2(0)= Right("0" & SplitArray2(0), 2)
End If
If Len(SplitArray2(1))<2 Then 
    SplitArray2(1)= Right("0" & SplitArray2(1), 2)
End If

SplitArray2(1) = splitArray2(1) & "T00:00:00"
strSDat = SplitArray2(2) & "-" & SplitArray2(0) & "-" & SplitArray2(1)
SplitArray= strSDat

End Function
```

Output File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLFeederRoot><Ad>
        <Ad_Number>d00524224</Ad_Number>
        <Start_Date>2016-08-20T00:00:00</Start_Date>
        <End_Date>2016-09-19T00:00:00</End_Date><Status>Run</Status>
    </Ad><Ad>
        <Ad_Number>d00524225</Ad_Number>
        <Start_Date>2016-08-20T00:00:00</Start_Date>
        <End_Date>2016-09-19T00:00:00</End_Date><Status>Run</Status>
    </Ad>
</XMLFeederRoot>
```